# Can I get the custom error message used with data annotation on controller MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Given a simplified class, like below:

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um nome de usuário")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Informe um e-mail válido")]
    [Remote("verificarUsernameCadastrado", "Validate", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public String Username { get; set; }
}
```

I'm relatively new on the MVC world and I was thinking.. Is there a way to get, in the controller, the custom error message used with data annotation?

For instance, if I access the property `Username` in an action, I'd like to get the error message that I gave for `EmailAddress` (in this case, "Informe um e-mail válido").

I can easily duplicate this message where I want to use, but I'd really like to know if it's possible to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using reflection, better used as an extension method:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this object instance, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
{
    var attrType = typeof(T);
    var property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (T)property .GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false).First();
}
```

Usage:

```
var errorMessage = client.GetAttribute<EmailAddressAttribute>("Username").ErrorMessage;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. That's why Stack Overflow is so great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can get this from the ModelState when you POST to the controller method:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(model MyModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         // normal processing
    }
    else
    {
        if (ModelState["Username"].Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            var msg = ModelState["Username"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've used this already. But in the current case, my model is null, so the ModelState doesn't have any errors. That's why I wanna directly get the custom error message that I gave. In any case, I upvoted your answer as I consider it useful. :)